# How can I read columns name of csv file in nodejs?

Tags: java, mysql, node.js, csv, backend

I have a CSV file and want to create a table with it in the MySQL database but my problem is when **I want to read the columns name in order to pass them in queries**, this is not working and had many issues.. anyone has an idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `csv-parser` package to read the columns. This following example can help you more about it.

```js
fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('headers', (headers) => {
        console.log(`Header: ${headers[0]}`)
    })
```

The first parameter of the event callback is an `Array[String]` containing the header names of the column.